# OpsWorks/Chef: multiple versions of a cookbook are required

Tags: mysql, nginx, version, chef-infra, cookbook

I am using OpsWorks. Multiple versions of `build-essential` cookbook are required because:

- `mysql` cookbook requires `'build-essential', '~> 1.4'`
- `nginx` cookbook requires `'build-essential', '~> 2.0'` (the version I have in my repo curently)

So when launching instance in OpsWorks, I get this error message:

```
================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================


Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
Could not satisfy version constraints for: build-essential
```

How could this conflict can be solved?

Thank you.

---

## Update 1

I ran into [*this thread*](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2013-08/msg00217.html). The last answer suggested to use role and environment, which cannot be applied in my case because I am using OpsWorks (OpsWorks does not have Chef server to manage multiple cookbook versions, and it also does not have such "role", "environment" concepts).

Comment: You have an unsolvable graph... There's nothing to "solve". Those cookbooks cannot be used in the same environment together - they are unsatisfiable constraints.

Comment: Thank you. My use case is very usual, nothing tricky here. And these 2 cookbooks (`mysql` and `nginx`) are very common so I guess some folks should have been facing the same problem. :| :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to use an older version of the nginx cookbook (v2.4.2, about a month old), that one [depends on build-essential ~> 1.4](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx/blob/v2.4.2/metadata.rb).

Also it sounds like you're using Chef-community cookbooks, It seems that OpsWorks itself has cookbooks for [mysql](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/v304/mysql) and [nginx](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/v304/nginx). (unfortunately named the same as the community ones). Have you evaluated if those are solutions for your situation?

Comment: Thank you Charlie! I think I will try community cookbooks option for now. Folks at AWS Support also let me know about these OpsWorks built-in cookbooks but I have not tried those since (1) I have been using "knife cookbook site install" command and (2) many of our cookbooks have been developed using these "nginx" and "mysql" cookbooks from community. I will try OpsWorks cookbooks later I think. Thanks again :)